2000s action/spy movie with CIA agent posing as flautist. Also, mind control
I don't know where or when this was released, though I do remember watching it on DVD several years back (I wanna say 2005ish, but don't quote me on that). It was in English. It follows a young guy (teens or twenties) working for the CIA who goes undercover as an exchange student to some sort of music academy (he pretends to be a flautist, and plays classical music from an iPod in his room so people will think he's practicing). There's also a scene where he lowers a microphone down a chimney or something to eavesdrop on a conversation.
The bad guy seems to be working on some kind of mind-control thing, and he gives someone a demonstration of it by making a dog play a piano. Later, fake-flute-guy ends up with a similar mind-control thing in his tooth, which is later blown out with a very precise explosive.
